# Page loading differently on every refresh

Tags: html, css

I'm very inexperienced when it comes to CSS and web design in general but I'm almost very sure it's not my error, because it works fine on everything except Google Chrome.

The page loads correctly... sometimes. Sometimes it doesn't.

I'm not sure exactly what to do about it but it only happens when I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Average+Sans|Quando">
```

This is how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K679J.jpg

Each subject should take the entire line, and not take only part of it.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Edit: Turns out it was caused by jquery .show, it was changing elements to :inline, for some reason it didnt happen everytime. Oh well. All good now..

Comment: Which photo is the correct one? Ie, which photo shows the fonts loaded correctly?

Comment: Happens to me too, a lot of times. Perhaps Google limits requests per IP/second?

Comment: check with inspect element, you don't have any javascript error that could make this error happen

Comment: You can always save a local copy of the file..

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in the CSS `#id-of-sidebar-wrapper > * { height: 1em; }` and in the HTML put a `<br>` after each one. BTW the CSS won't work if each item is part of the same element i.e. if there are no children to the sidebar.